# How to run 2 Locators on 2 seperate servers

Tags: apache, geode

Server 1, running below code:

```
start locator --name=locator1 --bind-address=xxx.xx.xx.111 --port=10334 --properties-file=..\config\gemfire.properties
```

Server 2,

```
connect --locator=locator1[10334]
```

then,

```
start locator --name=locator2 --bind-address=xxx.xx.xx.222 --port=10335 --properties-file=..\config\gemfire.properties
```

when listing members using:

```
list members
```

I do see both locators, but the 2nd locator seem to be stuck in the starting stage in an infinite loop. Logs were not very helpful. Am I starting the locators correctly?

Comment: If `list members` is showing both locators, why do you think locator2 is stuck?

Comment: The solution was disabling the firewall... I suspect some ports were open to being able to list the other locator, and some ports were closed, which did not allow to completely connect.

Comment: The answer is actually ports on the 2nd locator. so 1st locator can see 2nd locator because it has its firewall ports opened. but the 2nd locator cannot start due to not having its ports open to receive a connection from 1st locator!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue was **PORTS**... 
Completely disabling firewall allowed for the 2nd locator to start successfully.

Next step is to open correct ports.

More specifically, it's the ports on the 2nd Locator, as they are talking to **each other**